# warnings from git add . vs git add *

Tags: git

I'm slightly confused about different behaviours exhibited by `git add .` and `git add *`.

I'm adding a CodeIgniter website into my repo (as an initial add - the repo is currently empty).

When I use `git add .` all the files are added, and my `.gitignore` is respected. If I then try `git add *` (after resetting) I get a warning:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
contributing.md
```

However, it doesn't warn me about other files that are correctly ignored; for example, in my .gitignore I have

```
**/config/development/*
```

This directory only contains `database.php` and this file *is* ignored. Does the fact I don't get a warning a bug in git, or is there a rational explanation?

Comment: Since there were 2 distinct questions, and the first half has been answered, I'll remove the second half and make a new question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `git add *` at a bash prompt (or basically any UNIX-style shell prompt), the shell expands the `*`.  (Expanding globs is considered the shell's responsibility in UNIX, which has a number of minor symptoms, like this one.)

This means that as far as git can tell, you typed something like

```
git add aDiretory aFile anotherFile contributing.md someOtherDirectory
```

That is, it thinks you specifically asked it to add `contributing.md`.  When you specifically ask git to `add` a file that's *ignore*d, it doesn't do it (unless you give the `-f` option), and it prints a warning telling you why it didn't do it.

It doesn't warn about ignored files in subdirectories because you didn't specifically name those files to be added.  Naming a directory says implicitly that you want to add everything inside that directory *except what's ignored*, but what is ignored is silently skipped in this case.

And when you say `git add .`, you aren't explicitly naming any files - you just say implicitly that you want all the files under the `.` directory.  So no warnings.

Because git will not actually add the ignored file by default, this usually doesn't matter.  A more important difference between the two commands, though, is that when bash expands a `*` it will skip over filenames that start with `.`, like `.gitignore` itself.  So if you mean to add everything, using `.` (or something like `:/:.` to ensure you're talking about the worktree root) is often the more correct command.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation! Yeh - I'd already realised that files whose name began with a dot weren't included with `*` but were included with `.`

Answer (score 1):

You're running two different actions by the same command and it's [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion) that's key here. My repo has a pretty standard root directory;

```
$ ls
db/  docs/  packages/  reports/  scripts/  src/

$ ls .
db/  docs/  packages/  reports/  scripts/  src/
```

All sensible so far.

```
$ ls * | head
db:
Company.Data.Migrations/

docs:
ProjectX/
wiki/

packages:
Company.ProjectA.1.0.1/
Company.ProjectB.1.0.17/
... # and so on for every file
```

So the behaviour changes between `ls .` and `ls *`, why is that? See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/861077/is-it-possible-to-print-out-the-shell-expansion) for a hack to help think about filename expansion.

```
$ echo ls .
ls .

$ echo ls *
ls db docs packages reports scripts src
```

So bash is replacing `*` with *everything in the current directory* which is what we mean. `ls` much like `git add` behaves differently depending on if you specify `.` which means the current directory or if you specify `*` which means every file in this directory.